# Are there more recent (e.g post 2022) EU opinion polls on Turkey joining the EU?

Tags: european-union, public-opinion, turkey

I'm curious if public opinion in the EU countries on Turkey joining the EU has changed significantly in the past 6-7 years or so. I'm aware of one 2016 [survey](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-030-70890-0_11) in which the public opinion about Turkey joining the EU was overwhelmingly negative (in many EU countries of then):

> According to a YouGov survey in 2016, there is distinct hostility to Turkey joining the EU. In Germany (86%), Finland (83%), Denmark (82%), France (74%), Sweden (73%), and even in the United Kingdom (67%), there are large majorities against Turkey’s accession to the EU. In these countries, even Russia would be more welcome in the EU than Turkey (YouGov, 2016).

Have these numbers changed significantly since then?

Comment: https://d25d2506sfb94s.cloudfront.net/cumulus_uploads/document/ofavfkfy8j/YouGov%20Eurotrack%20EU%20membership%202.pdf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There have been at least a couple of post-2022 surveys on this topic, as shown below - (for/against/don't know)

| Survey Date | France | Germany | Spain | Italy | Poland |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [Mar-22](https://docs.cdn.yougov.com/96kojzktq9/YouGov%20-%20Ukraine%20EU%20membership.pdf) | 12/62/26 | 17/61/22 | 30/39/32 | 24/50/25 | - |
| [Jun-22](https://docs.cdn.yougov.com/v61mevh65q/Ukraine%20Wave%203%20compiled.pdf) | 13/65/22 | 15/67/18 | 35/39/25 | 26/44/29 | 42/30/28 |

It appears that attitudes in France and Germany have softened a little, with more respondents in favour of Turkey joining the EU, and more respondents undecided - compared to the responses in the [July '16 survey](https://d25d2506sfb94s.cloudfront.net/cumulus_uploads/document/q2g2dcxcv9/Eurotrack_July_CountriesPositiveNeg_Website.pdf) referred to in the question.

Comment: You should explain what the percentages are for. Are they "In favour"/"Against"/"Neutral"?

Comment: @Rekesoft I do so in the first sentence.